# Joomla - one admin panel for multiple sites

Tags: administrator

I'm trying to find some possible solutions to manage multiple Joomla sites through one administration panel, but couldn't find anything relevant.

Does anybody know if it is possible in Joomla 3.x? And if yes could somebody provide any possible solution, preferably non-commercial?

Many thanks!

Comment: You should search previous questions, you may find the answer. Hopefully this helps. [link one](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/360/how-to-manage-multiple-joomla-sites-and-their-updates) [link two](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/multiple-website-managment-with-joomla)

Comment: Another question that came to my mind is. Is this possible to pin a domain to admin panel and the by www page redirection change template for every of this page?